# Ошибка LoadError on line ["59"] компиляции gulp-compass

Tags: css, gulp, npm, compass

Установил ruby > в терминале IDE прописал

```
$ gem update --system
$ gem install compass
```

Но при компиляции compass, возникает ошибка

```
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[12:14:19] Starting 'compass'...
[12:14:19] Finished 'compass' after 17 ms
[12:14:22] LoadError on line ["59"] of C: cannot load such file -- compass-
normalize
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace


events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Compass failed
```

Установил `compass-normalize`  , пошла компиляция но во время ее работы  выдало предупреждение

```
[12:34:13] DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of 
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/ge
ms/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss:
#{} interpolation near operators will be simplified in a future version of 
Sass.
To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

  unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla} "$webkit-"#
{$experimen
tal-support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} 
"$microso
ft-"#{$experimental-support-for-microsoft} "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-
f
or-khtml}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 92 of 
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/compass-
core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss:
#{} interpolation near operators will be simplified in a future version of 
Sass.
To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:

unquote('"$ie6-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie6} "$ie7-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie7
} "$ie8-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie8}')

You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
```

Comment: У вас там кроме гема `compass` явно используется ещё и `compass-normalize`. Не видя кода, который на них ссылается, никаких подсказок дать больше не могу.

Comment: @D-side установил `compass-normalize` потом вот что выдаёт(обновил вопрос),может вам хватит данного кода для понимания процесса?) Компиляция проходит, но с задержкой 5с,

Comment: Это уже не ошибки, это предупреждения, и на скорость они не должны влиять. Видимо, сборка действительно происходит и эти секунд 5.

Comment: Терминал поругался лишь один раз, сейчас после перезапуска gulp , всё подхватывает как надо)) спасибо большое, оформите ответ я поставлю вам галочку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LoadError on line ["59"] of C: cannot load such file -- compass-normalize
```

Это общая ошибка загрузки гема. Согласно [рекомендациям RubyGems по именованию гемов](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/) (которым этот гем, кстати, не вполне следует) название (не считая расширения `.rb`) загружаемого главного файла гема совпадает с названием этого гема.

Так что он явно хочет ещё и гем `compass-normalize`. Установите и его:

```
$ gem install compass-normalize
```

Остальное — лишь предупреждения и мешать работе не должно.